# TypeError in Django

Tags: python, django, typeerror

Have this error while creating tutorial:
http://img718.imageshack.us/img718/2194/unled2bh.jpg

Have no freakin idea what's wrong. It's displays when i added this modifications:

settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'sklep.context_processors.koszyk'
)

EMAIL_PORT = 1025
EMAIL_SKLEPU = 'sklep@sklep-z-koszulkami.pl'
```

sklep/urls.py

```
url(r'^koszyk/$', 'koszyk', name="sklep_koszyk"),
url(r'^koszyk/dodaj/(\d+)/$', 'koszyk_dodaj', name="sklep_koszyk_dodaj"),
```

sklep/views.py

```
# coding: utf-8
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template import Context, loader
from django.conf import settings
from sklep.models import Produkt
from sklep.forms import ZamowienieForm

def koszyk(request):
    koszyk = request.session.get('koszyk', [])
    produkty = list(Produkt.objects.filter(pk__in=koszyk))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formularz = ZamowienieForm(request.POST)

        if formularz.is_valid():
            dane = formularz.cleaned_data
            tresc = loader.get_template('sklep/zamowienie.txt').render(Context({'produkty': produkty, 'dane': dane}))

            send_mail('Potwierdzenie zakupu', tresc, settings.EMAIL_SKLEPU, [dane['email']])
            send_mail(u'Zamówienie', tresc, dane['email'], [settings.EMAIL_SKLEPU])

            del request.session['koszyk']

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('sklep_koszyk'))
    else:
        formularz = ZamowienieForm()

    if koszyk:
        kontekst = {'koszyk': produkty, 'formularz': formularz}
    else:
        kontekst = {'koszyk': []}

    return direct_to_template(request, 'sklep/koszyk.html', extra_context = kontekst)

def koszyk_dodaj(request, id_produktu):
    koszyk = request.session.get('koszyk', [])
    if int(id_produktu) not in koszyk:
        koszyk.append(int(id_produktu))
    request.session['koszyk'] = koszyk
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('sklep_koszyk'))
```

context_processors.py

```
def koszyk(request): return {'stan_koszyka':len(request.session.get('koszyk', []))}
```

And i have added two templates.
Error shows up, when i enter /sklep/koszyk/ or /sklep/koszyk/dodaj/1/ URL...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the full path to your views in urls.py:

```
url(r'^koszyk/$', 'app_name.views.koszyk', name="sklep_koszyk"),
url(r'^koszyk/dodaj/(\d+)/$', 'app_name.views.koszyk_dodaj', name="sklep_koszyk_dodaj"),
```